# What is the more efficient way of loading an image from the web in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

for each `UITableViewCell` in my `UITableView`, I download an image from the web in the background thread. Then I update the imageView from the cell using the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
                //Background Thread
                // download the image in separate thread
                UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"someurl.com" ] ] ];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                    // this is called in the main thread after the download has finished, here u update the cell's imageView with the new image
                    cell.eventImageView.image = image;
                });
            });
```

I dont notice any lags when scrolling.

However, I like to know if there is a better way of doing this, and if so, how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: There are safer ways (preventing issues with cell reuse) and more standard ways (using common frameworks), so better, not necessarily more efficient. Did you search for existing solutions?

Comment: you can do with nsurlSession

Comment: [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) is the best...

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using SDWebImage ([can be found here on Git](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage))

I have written pages which sound similar to yours and it involves very simple code:

```
    // Set and load the images
    [cell.menuImageView sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {

        // Get rid of the activity indicator when the image has been loaded
        [activity stopAnimating];
    }];
```

There are, in my opinion, a number of advantages:

1) The library is flexible and gives you lots of options on how you want to download the image (these are only a few)

eg:

```
- (void)sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url
- (void)sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder
- (void)sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder options:(SDWebImageOptions)options
- (void)sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url completed:(SDWebImageCompletionBlock)completedBlock
- (void)sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder completed:(SDWebImageCompletionBlock)completedBlock
- (void)sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder options:(SDWebImageOptions)options completed:(SDWebImageCompletionBlock)completedBlock
- (void)sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder options:(SDWebImageOptions)options progress:(SDWebImageDownloaderProgressBlock)progressBlock completed:(SDWebImageCompletionBlock)completedBlock
```

2) The library caches the images meaning that the next time you don't have to download them again.

3) The library is well supported helping to trouble shoot issues

I personally started using the technique you used and found there were limitations and difficulties (adding activity indicators if the image was slow downloading etc) and then trialled a number of different asynchronous image downloaders and this one came out as the best

Hope it helps

Comment: SDWebImage is the way to go.

Comment: Can you explain tand he SDWebImage Options, and different methods you mentioned. I could not understand it. And Which method and which option do you use.

Comment: SDWebImage is a library which downloads and caches images from urls. You will need to download and add the library to your project - I linked the git repository in my answer. You can then choose the imageView you want to add an image to. You can see in my example that I am downloading an image and adding it too the cell.menuImageView. This is a custom imageView but you could also use cell.imageView to add it to a tableViewCell. You can see that the completion block also returns the image if you want to use it once it has been returned. Hope this helps