# Why using SDWebImage in a UITableViewCell triggers ImageViews not to render properly?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uitableview, sdwebimage

I have a UITableViewController containing my own cells that I dequeue in cellForRowAtIndexPath.
After dequeuing, I configure the cell and reload, asynchronously, the image for that cell.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PeopleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? PeopleListViewCell {
    cell.configureCell(headImageUrl)
  }
}
```

In my PeopleListView class,

```
func configureCell(img:NSURL) {
  if headImageView == nil { // to avoid allocation memory if not used
    headImageView = UIImageView()
    addSubView(headImageView)
  }
  headImageView.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()
  headImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(headImageUrl)
}
```

It works fine at the first loading and also while scrolling.

But when I push another viewController after

```
didSelectRowAtIndexPath
```

and come back to the list after the

```
dismissViewController()
```

I end up with a weird effect on my UIImageView , it's kind of a stacked or ghost image effect..
I'm having a hard time to figure out where is even triggered as when I m coming back from the viewController, cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called.

Comment: seems to be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551984/what-is-the-more-efficient-way-of-loading-an-image-from-the-web-in-a-uitableview

Comment: Some suggestions to locate the ghost.
First, comment out the view-related codes in your presenting ViewController, error still exists?
Second, try pushing your ViewController, still happen?
Third, you did something in viewWillAppear,  comment out them and see what happened?

Comment: I have no viewWillAppear implemented for now. If I don't push the viewController, all images looks fine. no problem at all, even when scrolling. It's when I push the 2nd viewController and then dismiss it that the tableView images become weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with asynchronous image loading.
The images I had was displayed within circles, with a cornerRadius.
Somehow, it was displayed without any problem at first load...

The issue here is I simply forgot the

```
headImageView.layer.maskToBounds = true
```

The result I got before setting maskToBounds to true was that I had the feeling that multiple images were located within the headImageView (UIImageView). If you ever have some artefacts like that, I hope this question/answer will help you.